# How do I multiply cell by cell values when both cells lie in range in google spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I want to multiply values in cells row by row and total them up in the resulting cell below, what is the formula?
the first column is ranging a1:a4, the second column ranging b1:b4.

I can write this: `=((a1*b1) + (a2*b2) + (a3*b3)).`

But i want nice and clean formula that uses ranges, like `=( (a1:a3)*(b1:b3))`

but it does not work
[image: fff]

Comment: why close it? googlespreadsheet questions are answered on SO!

Comment: like `=arrayformula(sum((a1:a3)*(b1:b3)))` ? or `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3,B1:B3)`

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out quickly myself, fortunately google uses similar formulas as in excel.

Excel has this nice `SUMPRODUCT(array1,array2)` which multiplies row by row and sum it up.

so the answer is this: `SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5,B1:B5)`